# How can I test a number of columns in a data.table for a specific value using R

Tags: r, data.table

This is my sample data

```
test <- data.table(name  = c("mike", "kate", "jeff"), ownership = c("1", "3", "4"), worth = c("1", "2", "3"), tax = c("4", "1", "4"))
```

I am trying to test if any rows (people) contain a row that contains "1".

I can do it like this

```
test <- test[ownership == "1" | worth == "1" | tax == "1", status := "yes"]
```

but I would like to make it a bit more concise.  Something like:

```
test <- test[any(c("ownership", "worth", "tax") %in% "1"), status := "yes"]
```

Comment: Are you checking columnwise or rowwise? Why is the last yes?

Comment: for every row I am checking the columns named (ownership etc)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rowSums` :

```
cols <- c('ownership', 'worth', 'tax')
setDT(test)[rowSums(test[, ..cols] == 1) > 0, yes := 'yes']
test

#   name ownership worth tax  yes
#1: mike         1     1   4  yes
#2: kate         3     2   1  yes
#3: jeff         4     3   4 <NA>
```

Another option suggested by @chinsoon12

```
setDT(test)[test[, .I[rowSums(.SD==1L)], .SDcols=cols], status := "yes"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that is more `data.table` way. I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks although will this work for strings? Mine are characters and I am not wanting to turn to strings

Comment: @tcl There is no difference in character and string in R and yes, this will work for both number and characters.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah, I added , na.rm = TRUE to deal with NAs which was causing a problem

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Reduce` with `.SD` (`data.table` methods)

```
cols <- c('ownership', 'worth', 'tax')
i1 <- test[, Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `==`, 1)) > 0, .SDcols = cols]
test[i1, yes := 'yes']
test
#   name ownership worth tax  yes
#1: mike         1     1   4  yes
#2: kate         3     2   1  yes
#3: jeff         4     3   4 <NA>
```